# VHDL Testbench : Output not changing

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'm currently learning about writing testbenchs for my VHDL components. I am trying to test a clock synchronizer, just made up of two cascaded D-type flip flops. I have written a testbench, supplying a clock and appropriate input signal stimuli but I see no output changing when I simulate, it just remains at "00".

I would be very grateful for any assistance!

EDIT: the dff component is a standard Quartus component, not quite sure how to get at the internal code.

Here is the component VHDL:

```
    library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;


--This device is to synchronize external signals that are asynchronous to the 
--system by use of two cascaded D-Type flip flops, in order to avoid metastability issues.

--Set the generic term Nbits as required for the number of asynchronous inputs to
--be synchronized to the system clock OUTPUT(0) corresponds to INPUT(0), ect.

entity CLOCK_SYNCHRONIZER is

    generic(Nbits : positive := 2);

    port
    (
        --Define inputs
        SYS_CLOCK   : in std_logic;
        RESET       : in std_logic;
        INPUT       : in std_logic_vector(Nbits-1 downto 0);

        --Define output
        OUTPUT      : out std_logic_vector(Nbits-1 downto 0) := (others=>'0')
    );
end entity;



architecture v1 of CLOCK_SYNCHRONIZER is

    --Declare signal for structural VHDL component wiring 
    signal A : std_logic_vector(Nbits-1 downto 0);

    --Declare D-Type Flip-Flop
    component dff
        port(D : in std_logic; CLK : in std_logic; CLRN : in std_logic; Q : out std_logic);
    end component;

begin

    --Generate and wire number of synchronizers required
    g1 : for n in Nbits-1 downto 0 generate 
        c1 : dff port map(D=>input(n), CLK=>sys_clock, Q=>A(n), CLRN=>reset);
        c2 : dff port map(D=>A(n), CLK=>sys_clock, Q=>output(n), CLRN=>reset);
    end generate;


end architecture v1;
```

And here is the testbench:

```
   library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity testbench is
end entity;


architecture v1 of testbench is 

    component CLOCK_SYNCHRONIZER

        generic(Nbits : positive := 2);

        port
        (
            --Define inputs
            SYS_CLOCK   : in std_logic;
            RESET       : in std_logic;
            INPUT       : in std_logic_vector(Nbits-1 downto 0);

            --Define output
            OUTPUT      : out std_logic_vector(Nbits-1 downto 0)
        );
    end component;

    constant Bus_width      : integer := 2;
    signal SYS_CLOCK        : std_logic := '0';
    signal RESET            : std_logic := '1';
    signal INPUT        : std_logic_vector(Bus_width-1 downto 0) := (others=>'0');
    signal OUTPUT       : std_logic_vector(Bus_width-1 downto 0) := (others=>'0');

begin

    C1 : CLOCK_SYNCHRONIZER
    generic map(Nbits=>Bus_width)
    port map(SYS_CLOCK=>SYS_CLOCK, RESET=>RESET, INPUT=>INPUT, OUTPUT=>OUTPUT);


    always : process
    begin
        for i in 0 to 50 loop
            INPUT <= "11";
            wait for 24ns;
            INPUT <= "00";
            wait for 24ns;
        end loop;
    WAIT;
    end process;

    clk : process
    begin

        for i in 0 to 50 loop
            SYS_CLOCK <= '1';
            wait for 5ns;
            SYS_CLOCK <= '0';
            wait for 5ns;
        end loop;
    WAIT;
    end process;






end architecture v1;
```

Comment: You haven't given the code for `dff`.

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to get at it. Its a standard component in Quartus. I know the component works I have it operating in a physical design, its just the testbench that I cant figure out.

Comment: Maybe try to generate clock in one of the standard ways: `clk <= not clk after 10 ns;`? Same for INPUT.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.3 Lexical elements, separators, and delimiters, para 2 - *In some cases an explicit separator is required to separate adjacent lexical elements (namely when, without separation, interpretation as a single lexical element is possible). ...*, para 4 - *...At least one separator is required between an identifier or an abstract literal and an adjacent identifier or abstract literal.* `5ns` is required to be `5 ns` or could be identified as an abstract literal containing a non-base character. A portability issue ignored in favor  of vendor lock-in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not compiled an entity to bind to the `dff` component. See [this example on EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/24iS), where you see the following warnings:

> ELAB1 WARNING ELAB1_0026: "There is no default binding for component
>   "dff". (No entity named "dff" was found)." "design.vhd" 45 0 ...
>   ELBREAD: Warning: ELBREAD_0037 Component /testbench/C1/g1__1/c1 : dff not bound.
>   ELBREAD: Warning: ELBREAD_0037 Component /testbench/C1/g1__1/c2 : dff not bound.
>   ELBREAD: Warning: ELBREAD_0037 Component /testbench/C1/g1__0/c1 : dff not bound.
>   ELBREAD: Warning: ELBREAD_0037 Component /testbench/C1/g1__0/c2 : dff not bound.

Given you have no configuration, this needs to have be called `dff` and must have exactly the same ports as the `dff` component, ie:

```
entity dff is
        port(D : in std_logic; CLK : in std_logic; CLRN : in std_logic; Q : out std_logic);
end entity;
```

(Google "VHDL default binding rules")

This needs to model the functionality of the `dff` flip-flop. I have *assumed* the following functionality:

```
architecture v1 of dff is
begin

  process (CLK, CLRN)
  begin
    if CLRN = '0' then
      Q <= '0';
    elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
      Q <= D;
    end if;
  end process;

end architecture v1;
```

You can see this now does something more sensible on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2bVq). (I haven't checked to see whether it is doing the *right* thing.)

BTW: why are you initialising this output? That seems a strange thing to do:

```
OUTPUT      : out std_logic_vector(Nbits-1 downto 0) := (others=>'0')
```

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 7.3.3 Default binding indication, para 2 "...A *visible entity declaration* is the first entity declaration, if any, in the following list:...c) An entity declaration denoted by L.C, where L is the target library and C is the simple name of the instantiated component. The *target library* is the library logical name of the library containing the design unit in which the component C is declared."  The mechanism for avoiding a configuration specification, your `dff` entity is found in the same working library as `testbench`. See para 4 for the identifying the architecture.